# how to make subfolders within images?

Tags: graphics

I am new to `LaTeX` and writing my thesis work and I have a lot of figures to add up in to my report. Now I want to make folders like `Chap1`, `Chap2`, ... inside my images folder containing figures for each chapter. I need help how to make it possible?

Comment: Do you mean how you can include your images in the document when you have them in subfolders?

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

Images can be included from anywhere if you specify the path. Something like `\includegraphics{./images/Chap1/figure-name}` should be fine, assuming that the `images` folder is a subfolder of the one containing the TeX. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you are anticipating a complex document structure where you want to `\input` files that are in subdirectories, take a look at the `import` package. This means you can have a main file that includes a line like this:

```
\subimport{../figures/case1/}{TexFile.tex}
```

or rather, `\subimport{path to file}{file name}`.

and then in that file you can do this:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
    \subfloat[Subcaption 1]{\includegraphics[width = 3in]{figure1a.png}}
    \hfill
        \subfloat[Subcaption 2]{\includegraphics[width = 3in]{figure1b}}
        \caption{Main caption}
\end{figure}
```

This means you no longer have to keep (too much) track of where your files are.